# Java 8: how to derive a ZoneId from ZoneOffset

Tags: java, date, java-8

I was reading the [API for the `ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class. It states that there are three tipes of ID:

1. derived from ZoneOffset
2. offset-style IDs with some form of prefix. Examples:

   ```
   ZoneId.of("GMT+2");
   ZoneId.of("UTC");
   ZoneId.of("UT+01:00");
   ```
3. region-based. Examples:

   ```
   ZoneId.of("Asia/Aden");
   ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+9");
   ZoneId.of("Asia/Aqtau");
   ```

But what is the right syntax for the first kind? Documentation says that

> *[ID from ZoneOffset] consists of 'Z' and IDs starting with '+' or '-'.*

What's the combination of String and `ZoneOffset` object I'm supposed to use to create a `ZoneId` of the first kind?

Comment: Erm... maybe I am missing the point, but the documentation clearly states that the prefix must be one among ""GMT", "UTC", or "UT", or "", and ZoneOffset.of() factory method takes an offset id whose format is also clearly specified. So if you want to create UTC+2, I guess you should use "UTC" as a prefix and "+2" as an offset id to ZoneOffset.of() ?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox that's right for the second kind of ID. I edited my question to include part of the answer, it may be useful for readers in the future

Comment: @LuigiCortese Please post your own answer as an Answer. Perfectly acceptable, and encouraged, to answer your own Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque edited my question and posted an answer. Just like a conversation with myself =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are actually two question to be answered here

## 1) What is the right syntax for the first kind?

This is it:

```
    ZoneId z;
    z = ZoneId.of("Z"); //for UTC
    z = ZoneId.of("+02:00"); 
    z = ZoneId.of("-02:00");
```

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#of-java.lang.String-) you can find the complete list

- Z - for UTC
- +h
- +hh
- +hh:mm
- -hh:mm
- +hhmm
- -hhmm
- +hh:mm:ss
- -hh:mm:ss
- +hhmmss
- -hhmmss

I wrongly thougt that

> 'Z' **AND** IDs starting with '+' or '-'

meant that you **always** needed a `Z` prefix (to compose something like `Z+02:00`). I think **OR** would be more appropriate.

## 2) What's the [needed] combination of String and `ZoneOffset` object?

No combination needed, you can either use a string or a `ZoneOffset` object:

```
    ZoneId z;
    z = ZoneId.of("+02:00"); 
    z = ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00").getId());
```